# Two variable function that's continuous on all linear paths, but nevertheless discontinuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Suppose we want to know $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}{f(x,y)}$.

The epsilon-delta definition of continuity (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) implies that "all paths" to $(0, 0)$ must result in the same limit for a function to be continuous.

But for some functions (i.e. ratios of polynomials in x and y), it's easy to set $y = \lambda x$ and determine the existence of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ such that

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x,\lambda_1x)} \neq \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x,\lambda_2x)}$.

Since any "path" to (0,0) can be approximated arbitrarily well (near the point (0,0)) by some line $y = \lambda x$, it looks like checking all linear paths would suffice in many circumstances.

Is there a [named] class of functions which satisfies this property (i.e. one can prove continuity by checking only linear paths)?

Is there a simple counter-example for when this scheme breaks?

Comment: To spot the error, state rigorously what you mean by "any path to (0,0) can be approximated arbitrarily well".  Either it will be false, or it won't imply the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding a counterexample, you can consider $$\begin{array}{l|rcl} 
g : & \mathbb R^2 & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\ 
    & (x,y) & \longmapsto & \frac{x^2 y}{x^4+y^2} \text{ for } (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 
    & (0,0) & \longmapsto & 0 \end{array}$$

For which you'll see the non-continuity along the path $x \mapsto (x,x^2)$ while $g$ is continuous at the origin along all lines.

For more insight, please have a look [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/continuity-multivariable-real-functions/).